# Removing ActionbarSherlock logs when BuildConfig.DEBUG

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, logcat

I have noticed that the library ActionBarSherlock display a lot of debug informations in my application, simply because there is a lot of lines like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
   Log.d(TAG, "[onCreatePanelMenu] featureId: " + featureId + ", menu: " + menu);
```

Fortunately, the log is displayed only on my debug device. Thanks to the `if` statement.
The big problem is that I would like to remove all the log on the debug device to focus on my code.

I know 2 solutions to avoid that:

1. Delete/edit all the logs in the library
2. Filter the logcat in
   Eclipse.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this and to "fake" the library by telling it we are not on a debug device?
I really would like to avoid the 2 above solutions.

Comment: Did you try set BuildConfig.DEBUG = false? It is not a good practice to change BuildConfig file but it should be ok during development

Comment: which version of Sherlock do you have ? I can not find any reference to BuildConfig.DEBUG

Comment: @blackbelt just look here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/ActionBarSherlock.java

Comment: All Android project should BuildConfig generated, it should be under gen folder, not src

Answer (score 4):

Open your ActionBarSherlock project
Open to the file `/gen/com/actionbarsherlock/BuildConfig.java`
And set `DEBUG = false`

Comment: Being an auto-generated and auto-regenerated file, this doesn't help much, unfortunately.

Comment: @Gábor don't rebuild library project after this changes has been made

Answer (score 0):

The debugging messages will only be shown when your app is running in debug mode. This means, if you did not define in the AndroidManifest.xml it will only show up on debug builds.

Once you create a production build it won't show up.

You can test this by setting the debuggable flag in your androidmanifest file manually and running it.
Also see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html for details about the options in the manifest file.

That said, it probably won't help you a lot because your app won't run in debug mode and you can't connect a debugger.

You could replace all reference to BuildConfig.DEBUG with something like your.package.name.SherlockConfig.DEBUG and define the debug variable there yourself. this way you can enable and disable the ActionbarSherlock debugging yourself.